# Url/filename of page being left in jQuery Mobile pageremove event

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the url / filename of the old page (the one being left) on a jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 pageremove event.

This works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
$(document).on("pageremove", function(e){
    console.log( $.mobile.path.parseUrl(e.target.dataset.url).filename);
});
```

But not in Internet Explorer.

How can I do this in a cross-browser compatible way?

*Update*

I can do this indirectly by setting a variable on a pageshow event,

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(e){
  last_page = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(e.currentTarget.URL).filename;
});
```

and then accessing that on pageremove.

It would be nice to get it directly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears not to be possible to see the filename of the page being left on a pageremove event in a cross-browser compatible way. ie you can't see which page is (potentially) being removed.

But the workaround I added earlier to the question itself has worked fine for me:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(e){
  last_page = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(e.currentTarget.URL).filename;
});

$(document).on("pageremove", function(e){
    console.log(last_page);
});
```

This works because the pageshow event happens after the pageremove event, and so last_page within the "on pageremove" still contains the value from when the page was displayed.